# Is it a compile time polymorphism or runtime?

Tags: java

If we call an overridden method of a subclass without using a reference variable of a super class, would it be run time polymorphism ?

Comment: Polymorphism is, by definition, a run time concept.

Comment: Yes. Please see the below for a complete explanation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355912/overloading-is-compile-time-polymorphism-really

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the Java world, yes, but not generally. What we Java folks call polymorphism is actually just one kind of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would. Java objects "decide" which version of a method to call based on the type of the value at runtime, not the value of the variable at compile time.

Consider the following classes:

```
public class A {
    public String foo() {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public String foo() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

All of the following invocations to `foo()` will return `"B"`:

```
// compile-time type is A, runtime type is B
A a=new B();
a.foo();

// compile-time type is B, runtime type is B
B b=new B();
b.foo();

// compile-time type is B, runtime type is B
new B().foo();
```