# Do we really need classes to implement polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

While going through an answer on this site, I came across a line which says

> Actually, you don't need classes for polymorphism at all

This comment was voted up. 
I know very well that

> Overridden methods are another way that Java implements the “one interface, multiple methods” aspect of polymorphism. Method Overloading supports polymorphism because it is one way that Java implements one-interface, multiple methods paradigm.

I don't think other than through classes, we could have implemented polymorphism in Java. If it is not so, can someone elaborate with a nice example?

Comment: No you cannot implement it without the classes

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355912/overloading-is-compile-time-polymorphism-really) has an answer that tries to distinguish "compile-time" from "run-time" polymorphism.  It's interesting in a way.  But when anybody talks about the importance of polymorphism in OOP, they're talking about run-time polymorphism only, because that's the kind of polymorphism that gives us all the advantages of reducing coupling, etc., that make OOP such a good idea.  Overloading does not give you that.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism is simply the ability for many (poly) things to take the same form or shape (morph). The term itself is explained in more depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/1031385#1031385).

In C++, for example, this can be done quite easily without classes:

```
long getNum (int x)  { return x + 1; }
long getNum (long x) { return x - 1; }
```

Do that and you'll get quite different results with the two lines:

```
long x = getNum (1);
long y = getNum (1L);
```

You can do *exactly* the same thing in Java with static methods, involving no classes at all, but it's a bit of a waste of the language:

```
public class Test {
    public static long getNum (int x)  { return x + 1; }
    public static long getNum (long x) { return x - 1; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println (getNum (1));
        System.out.println (getNum (1L));
    }
}
```

The output of that is:

```
2
0
```

Now you'll notice that there *is* actually a class in that Java code I posted but that's not a requirement to do polymorphism, it's more a requirement of the Java language to have *everything* embedded in a class. If you subscribe to the view that *that* make polymorphism dependent on classes, it also means that things like variable assignment and  incrementing `i` requires classes.

Comment: didn't that example make it to be dependent on class Test

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari, see my final paragraph.

Comment: @paxdiablo your answer is reasonable :)

Comment: Polymorphism means *one* thing, *many* forms. Your cited answer doesn't supoort your misinterpretation.

Comment: @EJP, the one thing is `getNum`, which comes in two forms, one taking an int, the other a long. It's no different to a square and circle both being a shape.