# Java 2 functions with superclass and subclass signatures - chooses superclass despite that subclass's type is subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, dynamic-dispatch, method-dispatch

I have the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public boolean equals(String other){
        return other == new Object();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other){
        return other == new Object();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "";
        Object b1 = new Main();
        System.out.println(b1.equals(s));

    }

}
```

As far as I am aware the `equals` method selection should work this way:
During compile time the signature will be selected, and since `s` is of compile-time type (e.g `type`), the method with parameter `String` should be selected, and since `b1` is an instance of `Main` then we will enter our `Main` implementation of `equals` rather than `Object`'s.

However, when debugging I see that I enter the `Main` implementation with the parameter of type `Object`.

I saw those 2 articles:
[Overloaded method selection based on the parameter's real type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572322/overloaded-method-selection-based-on-the-parameters-real-type) - doesn't explain my case, but a case in which the type of `s` would have been Object.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356435/4345843 - this answer, if true, as far as I understand supports my theory.

Would be happy for explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you assign `Main` instance to an `Object` variable. `Object` does not contain `equals(String)` method, and hence the only method that fits - `equals(Object)` - is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the beginning of the `equals(Object other)` method

```
if(other instanceof String)
return equals((String)other);
```

In addition to that i am not sure how the equals methods are useful since you are doing this  `return other == new Object();`. What you should probably be doing is something closer to `this.equals(other);`